# Amazon mobile ads Proguard

Tags: android, proguard, amazon-in-app-purchase

I'm using Amazon mobile ads (Just `com.amazon.device.ads.InterstitialAd` ad format).

What should I include in the Proguard file?

There is documentation on Proguard for [in-app-purchases](https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/earn/in-app-purchasing/docs/code-obfuscation#Setting%20Up%20Code%20Obfuscation%20for%20your%20Project), but not for mobile ads.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon stated in 2013 that they were fixing the proguard issue. So it should have been fixed. if you are still having errors try putting this in your proguard

```
-keep class com.amazon.device.ads.** { *; } 
-keep class **.R { } 
-keep class **.R$* { } 
-keepattributes *Annotation* 
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.** 
-dontwarn com.amazon.** -keep class org.apache.** {*;} 
-keep class com.amazon.** {*;}
```